# Can't get MySQL server running on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mysql

I had MySQL up and running several days ago with the help of a friend, but after a reboot I can't get it to startup.

My understanding is that I am to run a command prompt as administrator, go the bin folder, type in

```
mysqld
```

which returns the following message:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details)
```

There are no MySQL processes running, but there is a MySQL56 service running.

tia for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqld` is the MySQL server process. The `MYSQL56` service will have started this if the service is running, You may not see it in task manager because it is started using one of the default Windows service accounts, rather than your user account. To see it you'd need to click the `Show Processes From All Users` button in task manager, which requires that you are an Administrator.

Presuming the `MySQL56` service is running, you shouldn't need to run `mysqld` manually, since an instance of the service is already running

Try closing the instance you started manually and then connect to the server using the command
`mysql -u root -p`

You will be prompted for a password. This is the MySQL root password you supplied during installation.

Comment: Thx. You said "Try closing the instance". How do I do that? Sorry, total newbie here.

Comment: Also, when I use mysql -u root -p and enter through password I get: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I did not setup a password.

Comment: When you type `mysqld`at a command prompt, a copy (instance) of mysqld is launched. I was recommending that you close this copy before trying to connect.

Comment: if you don't have a password, try the same mysql command without the -p switch i.e.
`mysql -u root`

Comment: How do I close this copy? What's the command/process?

Comment: If you launched a copy of `mysqld` in a command prompt as described in your question, simply close that window